# A problem with a prepositional phrase in the sentence of a poem

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions, prepositions, word-usage

The following is the sentence:

> Is it the graceful blessing
>   that vivifies the existence
>   and whose nectar **for seekers**
>   is an unparalleled opulence?

My problem is with the position of the prepositional phrase **for seekers**.

If it is not used in that location, then it will be difficult to manage a rhyming scheme.

And I don't know if 'the' should be used before seekers.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Anyway, you have freedom in poetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct to me. I write poetry/songs, and I firsthand have thought that locations of prepositional phrases were an issue. However, after receiving feedback from teachers throughout my education (along with submitting poetry with these types of 'issues'), they explain that poetry has no limit. Most poets break some rules of grammar and all that, so you wouldn't be the first.

I hope that helps.

Comment: should we use 'the' before seekers and what about the use of comma

Comment: I suppose you could use 'the,' but you aren't necessarily forced to do so.

Comment: Poetry needs rhythm as well as rhyme. In order to have rhythm one often has to move clauses around to get the emphases correctly in balance. So poetry _has_ to be more flexible than written grammar.

Comment: @AsaMatthews Regarding poetry you may wish to see my profile (which has details of my website).